# Hiding Information in a SharePoint List

Tags: workflow, infopath, sharepoint-designer

If several employees add their data to a SharePoint List (Change of Address) how do I hide the employees' address from the other employees and is this possible? I have been working in the SharePoint Designer trying to create a workflow or even add this to a current workflow that allows employees to fill out a form that is added to a SharePoint List.

The other problem is this workflow does not display the employees' current data in the form to allow changes/edits to an address. This can work if I use a customizable InfoPath form, but I would like to keep the employees from having to select Add New Item if at all possible. The only other possible conclusion I can come up with for this is to create a link that will allow employees to bring up the workflow form. I don't want them searching for the form either; I'd rather keep it handy in the List.

Comment: By 'hide' do you mean that the information should simply not be visible or do you mean that other employees CAN NOT have access to it?  (i.e. presentation only or security)

Comment: @Dave Wise - Other employees CAN NOT have access to other employee data, just their own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set-up the Item Level Permission for the list or library so only users who created the item can view/edit etc.

check out this article that explains how to achieve this in SP2010

[Item Level Permission 2010](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2010/03/configure-item-level-permissions-for-document-libraries-part-2/)

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this and now receive an error that says "Condition is not valid for the associated list." I have checked in a few different places to see a resolution for this error message. What is interesting is when I "Check for Errors" the message indicates --> "The workflow contains no errors." I have checked : [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/troubleshoot-workflow-errors-HA010237912.aspx) to trouble shoot this, but I dont think they have what Im looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A couple things offhand, Set the default view of the list to be filtered by Created By equals [ME].  You can also set the item level permissions in the list to Read Only their own and Edit only their own.

Comment: @PirateEric- Would I have to do that at everyones computer who is using SharePoint? Read Only their own and Edit only their own? OR can I do this at the Admin/Farm Level? Or would I/Can I do thi using SharePoint Designer in a workflow? I'm still learning this workflow bit works. Thank You

Comment: The read and edit only their own is set on the list in question.  Click on your list, Settings, List Settings, Advanced Settings.